# How to fix Debug error "Run-Time check failure"

Tags: c++

I'm creating a programme about drone.I got no error when building it but when it comes to debugging this error appears

[image]

Can anyone explain to me why this happens? and how to solve this? I'm sorry if my coding line is hard to understand and not organized because im still learning.And i do know that the coding line itself doesnt make sense (drone part) thank you so much

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    void manualMode();
    void defaultMode();


    int speed, timeTofly, operation;
    int angle = 90;

    int main() {
        int mode = 0, part = 3;
        double flyLevel;
        int obstacleSensor = 0, timer = 3, AccelerometerSensor = 0, tempSensor = 25;
        char startPause;
        cout << "Drone Flying Technology" << endl;
        do {
            cout << "Choose Mode: (1)Default, (2)Manual \n";
            cin >> mode;
            if (mode == 1)
                defaultMode();
            if (mode == 2)
                manualMode();
        } while (mode == 0);

        cout << "Choose how to fly: (1)Upper , (2)Lower , (3)Upper and Lower \n";
        cin >> part;
        switch (part) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            flyLevel = 0.5;
            break;
        case 3:
            flyLevel = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (obstacleSensor == 0) {
            do {
                cout << "Press (S) to Start,and swing the propeller." << endl;
                cin >> startPause;
                cout << "LED is On\n";
                while (AccelerometerSensor != flyLevel) {
                    AccelerometerSensor++;
                }
                cout << "Flying session Started! Time Left:" << timeTofly << endl;
                cout << "Eagle eye Operation Started!\n";
                timeTofly = timeTofly / 2;
                cout << "Crusing mode initiate Time Left:" << timeTofly << endl;
                timeTofly = timeTofly / 2;
                cout << "Free fly commenced Time Left:" << timeTofly << endl;
                timeTofly = 0;
                startPause = 'P';
            } while ((startPause == 's') || (startPause == 'S'));
        }
        cout << "End!\nLED is Off";
        return 0;
    }


    void manualMode() {
        cout << "Enter drone speed (knot) \n";
        cin >> speed;
        cout << "Enter Time to fly: \n";
        cin >> timeTofly;
        cout << "Choose Operation: (1)Fully manual, (2)Normal Orientation, (3)Free orientation, (4)FPV racing, (5)All\n";
        cin >> operation;
    }
    void defaultMode() {
        int howtofly;
        cout << "how to fly: (1)Circle, (2)Altitude Hold, (3)Free orientation";
        cin >> howtofly;
        switch (howtofly) {
        case 1:
            speed = 30;
            timeTofly = 3;
            break;
        case 2:
            speed = 40;
            timeTofly = 3;
            break;
        case 3:
            speed = 60;
            timeTofly = 3;
            break;
        }


        char object[25];
        char imei[5];
        float m1;

        ofstream outputFile("object to record and preferred speed.txt", ios::out);
        cout << "Please enter object to record,your drone imei number and video frame per second:\n";
        cout << "\nPress <ctrl> + z to stop. \n";

        while (cin >> object >> imei >> m1)
        {
            outputFile << object << " " << imei << " " << m1 <<endl;
        }





    }
```

Comment: It means the array `imei` on the stack trace was corrupted (a.k.a overwritten) by some other variable. You should really learn [how to use a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: You can reach more people who might help you if you provide a textual quote of the error message right here.

Comment: Did you hit "Retry"?  That is what that the assert message box is requesting you do to debug the application.

Comment: What input did you enter? `char object[25];` can take only 24 characters, `char imei[5];`  only 4 (last one is for the terminating `'\0'`). Probably you have an overflow here, it's better to use `std::string`.

Comment: Use `std::string`s as @churill said. Also, 4 chars for an [imei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMEI) sounds really small.